# Is a traveling magnetic field identical to the field of a moving magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

A traveling magnetic field is created by means of applying out-of-phase currents to a number of coils. Is it identical to that created by a moving magnet, including relativistic effects?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "identical". A local observer can't tell the difference for a suitable choice of coil excitations, but an assembly of coils can potentially produce magnetic fields that can not be produced by moving a single magnet (or even any number of magnets).

Comment: You planning a new type of rail gun? :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne Potentially the coil generated field could move faster than light. I am interested in what the practical differences might be, and how sub-luminally they can be identified.

Comment: Isn't a "travelling magnetic field" produced by a long series of coils analogous to [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48328/12613)?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Partly, but the question is really about how to tell the difference between the two possible origins of the field

Comment: I had a hunch that you would be asking about the superluminal phase velocity case. :-) That's why I said that coil assemblies can produce fields that can't be produced with a single moving magnet. Can we detect the differences? Of course, just not locally. The physical vacuum is a linear medium, so to detect the phase and amplitude of n transmitters unambiguously, we need, at least, n receivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same, at least at the scales of size, distance, and field variability at which the different generating methods cannot be discerned.