# Can an object appear to travel faster than the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light

An object cannot travel faster than the speed of light.

But given a video of an object travelling at $0.5c$, could one speed the video up so that the object appeared to be travelling at $1c$, $2c$ or more?

Or would something prevent this?

Comment: Nothing would prevent this, but then the video wouldn't reflect something that would actually happen.

Comment: You could play the video backwards, or upside-down, or through a mirror, and those would still show possible physical situations. But there's no symmetry associated with speeding it up.

Comment: Avoiding the  "speeding the video up" issue, you can think that an object is approaching you at superluminal velocity because of an optical illusion.  Jets from a quasar are one example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminal_motion

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "appear". An object that is traveling towards you does actually "appear" to be traveling faster than the speed of light. Let's say a nuclear rocket traveling at a speed of 0.8c takes off from Alpha Centauri some 4 light years away and you can see the enormous engine burn at takeoff here on earth. The light of the launch event took 4 years to get here. The rocket takes 5 years to get here, so the "apparent" travel time is only one year and the rocket seems to be traveling at 4c.

Comment: This seems related to questions like "can the edge of a shadow travel faster than the speed of light," which I'm sure have been covered before somewhere on this site. Edit: for example, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48328/is-it-really-possible-to-break-the-speed-of-light-by-flicking-your-wrist-with-a

Comment: @sumelic also the phase velocity of radio waves in a waveguide, due to "the beach analogy".

Answer (score 4):

No. There is nothing to prevent such faster than light appearances. The rule is simple: No actual thing (information) can travel at a speed greater than the speed of light.

When the considered particle appears to travel at a speed greater than the speed of light in your video, there is a non-local distribution of information - set up a priori. This distribution exhibits itself as something travelling at a speed greater than that of light. But no actual particle/information travels at a speed greater than the speed of light in this entire scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing can prevent you from speeding up the video, but there are ways to tell if you are looking at a sped-up video or at a real video of an object traveling at a speed close to or equal to $c$ (or greater than $c$, if we can assign any meaning to this concept).

Think about [length contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction): if you are looking at a spaceship traveling at a speed $v$, from your frame of reference its length in the direction of motion will appear to be

$$L = \frac {L_0} \gamma = L_0 \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$$

where $L_0$ is the length of the spaceship in its rest frame.

If $v \in [0,c]$, $\gamma >1$, so the spaceship will appear shorter to you. If $v=c$, we would have $L=0$: the spaceship will look like a segment from your frame of reference (the contraction only happens in the direction of motion, so it would appear like a segment and not like a point).

This shortening effect will not be present in a sped-up video, so you would be able to tell if the video is really showing a spaceship moving at a speed close to $c$ or just a sped-up version of the same video.

If $v>c$, the formula above breaks down because $\gamma$ becomes imaginary, but you would still be able to tell a sped-up video from a real one...also because you know that no physical object can travel at a speed $v>c$.