# Exceeding the speed of light by means of a shadow, will we ever be able to transmit information faster than light?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, faster-than-light, causality, information

I bumped into this:
[Can a shadow move faster than the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335537/)
while trying to see if I could find out anything about what I'd been thinking for 2 years now.
Bear with me here, cause I'm only gonna copy-paste what I'd written at another location where no one bothered to answer because... Well... I guess no one's a science amateur there.
So here it goes:
There are so many who, having answered this question, they either started to unsuccessfully compare light with shadow, or for ex. saying that shadow is not information.
For starters, shadow does indeed happen to be information aswell, if you're willing to take into account that one may use light to transmit the info through Morse code. So, in other words, it is the second part of the light-shadow information transmitting method, if you will.
And then, to answer the actual question, one might still be able to really speed up the information through this light-shadow process.
I'm using “might”, not “may”. And that's because, while at this time we don't have the means to do what I'm about to explain, and not being doable at this point in history shouldn't be considered a disproof, still there might come a time when we'll start thinking about those means. And just think about holo-images, just to give one example.
A whole lotta phrases there coming from me! But you guys out there can think in a logical manner, I could bet on that :-)

Alright. So, I'm gonna upload a drawing I just did.
On it, you have the light source coming from above. It falls on an object traveling at vo (velocity object) on a horizontal plane. Which in turn further projects a shadow on the diagonal plane below, which is traveling at vs (velocity shadow).
I'm not going to refer to the initial and terminal velocities, when the object started to move and then braked and stopped. Cause at those points vo = vs, that's a fact.
But in between, on a segment, if you choose a speed for vo & calculate vs separately (because remember, you won't be able to measure vs), you'll see that for example when the diagonal lies at 45°, then vs = 1.4142*vo, although I'm not sure about the constant. It was just a wild guess, based on the diagonal of a square.
Extrapolating this, would bring us to the case where a diagonal raised to 89.9°, vs would tend towards infinity.

[image]

So think about vo being some 250,000 km/s. Or even 200,000.
So… I'm not an engineer, and I wouldn't know how to put this in practice, but my gut feeling is it's doable somewhere in the near future, talking tens of years from now.
Getting back to Morse code, I'll say it again in other words: it's not how fast we're hitting the code, it's how fast we're sending it. Once the information arrives at the destination, it can then be decoded.
Again: I'm not talking about typing it. Instead it's all about transmitting it.
Anyway, Morse code is just the basic stuff. I repeat: engineers are the ones that could think of something.
Just think about communicating with Mars. We could probably skip those 25 minutes of waiting for the messages to arrive. Cause those are actually based on radio waves which travel only close to the speed of light.
Or... think about projecting holograms... Not on Earth.

Comment: As the answers in the question you linked try to explain, you can easily make a shadow move much faster than light, but that doesn't let you send any information faster than light. You mentioned using Morse code to transmit data, but that's not an issue: modern digital technology handles data in the form of on / off signals that switch millions of times per second.

Comment: I edited my post somewhere in the middle, where I specifically stated that it's over thing when we talk about typing/hitting the Morse code, and another when we talk about effectively sending the info. Why not try to imagine what I'd drawn there? 

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "it's over thing when we talk about typing/hitting the Morse code". Relativity doesn't stop you from using some code to send millions of words per second, but if you're sending that data to a place that's 10 light-years away, it will take 10 years to get there.

Answer (score 1):

> shadow does indeed happen to be information

Yes, but who is *sending* that information?

You can send information by pointing a laser at a screen twitching the projected spot back and forth between two different points on the screen, but the information does not originate at one point on the screen and flow toward the other. It flows from *you* to whoever else is watching the screen.

When you decide to twitch the laser, the fact that you twitched it moves from your hand to the screen *at the speed of light*, and then from the screen to the eyes of whoever is watching *at the speed of light.*  How fast the spot appears to "move" across the screen does not even enter in to the equation.

Answer (score 0):

> it's not how fast we're hitting the code, it's how fast we're sending it

One can never send the code faster than the velocity of light. You could encode a signal on the flat plane so that the shadow carries a meaning. But the creation of the shadow relies on the lack of light, and to "see" the shadow, light has to shine before and after, and that can only arrive at the velocity of light on the inclined plane  no matter the speed of the shadow itself.