# How can a shadow move faster than light?

Tags: speed-of-light, faster-than-light, shadow

So I understand that similar questions has been asked before. There is a specific aspect I don't understand which I don't think has been explained.

If I shine a light on a surface and then I add a barrier, isn't there still a some photons remaining on the other side of the barrier which will still be travelling toward the same surface. Therefore, wouldn't the shadow moving across the surface be travelling at a slower speed than that of light. I've made a rough illustration of what I mean. (Sorry it's an MSPaint job).
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259732/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48328/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335537/2451 and links therein.