# Can it be that apparent faster than light speed of shadow/laser dot is not actually faster than speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, laser, faster-than-light

Many state that in fact laser dot or shadow can move faster than light but I beg to differ.

My question, rather statement would be that nothing, not even apparent illusion of shadow or laser dot is moving faster than light. If we were to point laser at Moon and if we were to move it across it's surface it wouldn't be moving faster than speed of light because each photon takes time to travel to the moon and when laser has been pointed to the new direction we would see that apparent lag until dot would reach new pointed location. Minutephysics states that if we were to do the same it would take 0.00005 seconds for dot to cross distance of 3,500,000 meters. *But how can it be because it takes time for photons to reach new direction (more than 1 second)? And that time is dictated by the speed of light? Can this applied to any illusions of this kind?* That even if we would to move laser dot along long surface it would never move faster than speed of light but rather at the same speed because there is lag until dot reaches new location at time it takes it's exactly the same amount of time as it would take light to move between that two positions.

I am surly missing something and I want to be corrected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it really possible to break the speed of light by flicking your wrist with a laser pointer?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48328/)