# Does special relativity limit quantum field propagation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, path-integral, causality, klein-gordon-equation

For the classical Klein-Gordon field, the motion of a wavepacket is constrained slower than the speed of light for $m^2 >0$ and constrained to exactly the speed of light for $m = 0$ (the equation of motion is the wave equation in that latter case). However, in quantum mechanics, in determining amplitudes of propagation between different field configurations, the path integral integrates over all paths, not just the classical path.

I expect the fields $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ at equal times commute, and so we can find simultaneous eigenstates of all the field operators $\phi$ at equal times. I will label these eigenstates by a function $f(\cdot)$: $\phi(0, \vec{x})|f(\cdot)\rangle = f(\vec{x})|f(\cdot)\rangle$. I expect that the amplitude for propagation from field configuration $|f(\cdot)\rangle$ to $|g(\cdot)\rangle$ in time $t$ is $$\langle g(\cdot)| e^{-iHt}|f(\cdot)\rangle = \int_{\phi(0, \vec{x}) = f(\vec{x}),\phi(t, \vec{x}) = g(\vec{x})}  D\phi \, e^{iS},$$ where $$S = \int d^n x \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi$$ is the usual Klein-Gordon action.

In classical mechanics, some field configuration with finite support about the origin cannot, at the very next instant in time, have support far away from the origin. However, that is not clear in QFT because the integral is over all paths, not just classically allowed paths.

*Can $\langle g(\cdot)| e^{-iHt}|f(\cdot)\rangle$ be nonzero for widely separated field configurations?*

If yes, an example calculation showing a nonzero amplitude would be appreciated.

For an example of "separated" field configurations, I have in mind something like $f(\vec{x}) = e^{-L^2/(r^2-|\vec{x}|^2)}\theta(r^2-|\vec{x}|^2)$ and $g(\vec{x}) = e^{-L^2/(r^2-|\vec{x}-\vec{s}|^2)}\theta(r^2-|\vec{x}-\vec{s}|^2)$ for some $|\vec{s}| > 2r$. At very short times, can the amplitude for propagation between such configurations be nonzero?

---

I'll add a few comments on causality. A typical QFT with Lorentz symmetry enjoys causality. For example, the existence of a unitary representation of the proper, orthochronous Lorentz group and Lorentz invariance of the vacuum implies that the commutator (or anticommutator, for a fermion field) of two fields vanishes at spacelike separation. This property of the commutators, along with a few more assumptions, generally rules out faster-than-light communication (e.g. the open-access [Eberhard and Ross)](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/5604n7md).

In this question, I identify a quantity that I believe may "move" faster than light/evolve faster than allowed classically. Even if this quantity does evolve more quickly than naively expected, this still does not mean the end of causality; consider [this toy example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48328/is-it-really-possible-to-break-the-speed-of-light-by-flicking-your-wrist-with-a). However, if it does turn out that we have non-zero amplitudes for propagation between widely separated field configurations at arbitrarily short times, I would still appreciate a comment on resolving anxieties about causality.

Comment: Let’s say I send you an electron from Earth to Mass and you receive it simultaneously (in some reference frame). How would you know if this was my electron or some other electron that “popped into existence” (really, was created by your measurement device)? As you note correctly in your question, to transfer information it is insufficient to detect a particle. The vanishing (anti-)commutator guarantees superluminal information transfer is impossible, and since it is one of the Wightman axioms for QFT, all QFT have this property

Comment: Related concept: [correlation doesn't imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation)

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov and Chiral Anomaly, thank you for the reasonings about if there were a non-zero propagation amplitude between widely separated field configurations, then it wouldn't be anything to worry about in terms of causality. Do you know if the amplitude is nonzero?

Comment: @user196574 in all QFTs the amplitude is nonzero, but exponentially (for massive particles) decaying.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov Thank you, could you please share a source for that?

Comment: @user196574 any QFT textbook explains this, eg Peskin-Schreder

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov Could you give the page from P+S? I know that Peskin and Schroeder calculate the expectation value of a commutator in the vacuum $\langle0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle$, but I didn't think they calculated the quantity $\langle f(\cdot)| e^{-iHt}|g(\cdot)\rangle$ where $|f(\cdot)\rangle$ is a field eigenstate.

Comment: @user196574 that quantity is called the propagator and it is a very well known calculation. P—S have the result and so does Wikipedia. For K-G free scalar, the propagator is a certain modified Bessel function of the invariant interval, which for spacelike separated points decays exponentially. Sorry, I don’t have a copy of P-S to give you a page number.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov I am afraid I do not see the connection between the propagator from QFT and the quantity $\langle f(\cdot)| e^{-iHt}|g(\cdot)\rangle$. I was under the impression that the propagator from QFT does not equal a matrix element of the time evolution operator. I am happy to move the discussion to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116132/discussion-between-user196574-and-prof-legolasov).