# Do shadows have mass?

Tags: mass, shadow

It sounds like a joke but I just want to know if shadows have mass, since shadows are formed when there is blocking of light. It forms a black pattern with no energy therefore it has no mass.

Comment: Only Peter Pan's shadow.

Comment: Here's a Vsauce episode, where Michael asks a similar question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Do1lm9IevYE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A shadow is a lack of light. Therefore, a shadow has no mass, for a shadow is not an object or energy. Shadows can go faster than light in certain cases because they are not objects. In the same way, a vacuum has no mass.

Comment: Can you explain in what cases shadows can go faster than light?

Comment: @Prahar http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63434/ and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTvcpdfGUtQ

Comment: @prahar I have read this stuff as if it is a violation of GR(although Jimmy has given a good justification on the stuff), in Michio Kaku's book - _physicis of impossible_

Answer (score 0):

Shadow is not a matter; so it does not have mass. The simple characteristics of matter are: They have mass and take up space.