# Does darkness manifest instantaneously?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, shadow

If we shine a beam of light to an object 1 light year away it takes a year for light to shine on it. Now if we block the light source would it take 1 year for the object to become dark or would it become dark instantaneously?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speed of Dark experiment, does it \*really\* travel faster than light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259732/)

Comment: I completely disagree with this question being closed: is not at all a duplicate of the other cited question: the other question has to do with the speed of a moving shadow while this one has to do with light speed and the existence of an universal reference frame for time. This is a classical example of lazy enforcement of the site policy.

Comment: @Noumeno what should I do now?