# Why phase velocity has no physical significance for a matter wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-velocity

The following is quoted from my book:

> "The wavelength of a matter wave given by $λ= \frac{h}{p}$ has physical significance; its phase velocity $v_{p}$ has no physical significance. However, the group velocity of the matter wave is physically meaningful and equals the velocity of the particle."

But why the phase velocity of a matter wave has no physical significance. Can someone please explain? I am so confused. Please help.

Comment: This is a fairly common question and already has answers here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480700/264848.

Comment: Related : **(1)** [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is E? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207). **(2)** [Which of the following two formulas is the correct wavelength expression of a relativistic electron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/612836/which-of-the-following-two-formulas-is-the-correct-wavelength-expression-of-a-re/612892#612892).

Answer (score 0):

The [de Broglie relation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/debrog.html) you are discussing belongs to the first studies that led to the theory of quantum mechanics. Now it is a useful approximation for the complexity of the final theory.

The formula, used for a massive particle, and an experiment with a collection of this particle gives the wave behavior which is predicted by quantum mechanics for such ensembles. *But* the quantum mechanical calculations are not for one particle:  The **probability** of finding a particle in an experiment with the same boundary conditions, is given by $Ψ^*Ψ$ where $Ψ$ is the quantum mechanical solution of the problem. This wave function is a main [postulate of quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html).

As any phases in this mathematical formulation have to do with the probability, the phases in $Ψ$ are not connected to the particle's phase velocity in space. For [a free particle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/Scheq.html) the wave function is a plane wave:

$$
\Psi(x,t)=Ae^{ikx-i\omega t}
$$

The velocity is there, but the phase in the expression only affects the *probability* of measurement of the particle. More on the wavefunction and its connection with the de Broglie relation and Heisenberg uncertainty, [here](http://physics.mq.edu.au/%7Ejcresser/Phys201/LectureNotes/WaveFunction.pdf).