# Seeming violation-wave travelling faster than speed of light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, waves, faster-than-light, phase-velocity

Consider the basic relation $$E=\sqrt{(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2}.$$

Every particle possesses a wave nature and it depends on the situation in which one among the two is perceptible...

Consider a particle with rest mass $m$. If we consider the speed of De-Broglie Waves, as usual for a wave $$v_{wave}=\nu \lambda.$$ And since we are taking relativistic effects into account, let's write $$\lambda =\frac{h}{\gamma mv}$$ where $\gamma$ denotes the Lorentz factor $\gamma =1/\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}$, and $v$ the speed of the particle. Now clearly the energy of the wave could be written as $E=h \nu$. And for the particle, Energy is equal to $\gamma mc^2$. So clearly
$$h \nu =\gamma mc^2.$$
Now plugging into $v_{wave}=\nu \lambda$, we get
$$v_{wave}=\frac{\gamma mc^2}{h}\frac{h}{\gamma mv},$$
or
$$v_{wave}=\frac{c^2}{v}.$$ Doesn't this seem to go against what we know, that the velocity of the wave is less than or equal to $c$?

So can anyone point out what's the mistake here? Does this have anything to do with phase or group velocity?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6912/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Related  :  [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is  E ? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you have calculated is the [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity), $v_p$, of the de Broglie wave associated with the particle. The phase velocity can be greater than $c$, and indeed it is always greater than $c$.

The velocity of the particle is the [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity), $v_g$, and as you have demonstrated the two are linked by:

$$ v_p v_g = c^2 $$

The group velocity must always be less than $c$ and that implies the phase veocity must always be greater than $c$.