# The phase velocity of a massive field is greater than $c$

Tags: special-relativity, waves, speed-of-light, faster-than-light, phase-velocity

Assuming $c=1$, $v=\frac{\omega}{k}=\frac{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}{k}>1$, for $m \neq 0$. Why is it not an issue that this $v$ is greater than the speed of light?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6912/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/503967/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The physical speed is the group velocity
$$
v_g= \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k} = \frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} <1.
$$
The phase velocity
$$
v_\phi = \frac{\omega}{k}
$$
is not relevant.

Comment: Why is $v_g$ interpreted as the physical velocity? It has the units of s/m

Comment: It has the same units as $\omega/k$  i,.e dimensionless.  it is the speed at which energy and information travel.

Comment: But if we didn't set $c=1$, this would have units s/m

Comment: I got it. The numerator would have a pc^2 if we don't set natural units.